# maxIndex of an MVector

Tags: haskell

[`Data.Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1) includes a function `maxIndex` with type `maxIndex :: (Ord a) => Vector a -> Int` that returns the index of the `maximum` value in that Vector. I'm working with mutable Vectors, however, and `MVector` doesn't have `maxIndex` defined for it.

What's the best way of getting the data I want out of the `MVector` I have? My code currently is:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MV
import           Control.Monad.ST
import           Control.Monad               (mapM_)

type MaxIndex = Int

step :: forall s. MV.MVector s Int -> MaxIndex -> ST s ()
step vec i = do
    n <- MV.unsafeRead vec i
    MV.write vec i 0
    let l      = MV.length vec
        (k, x) = n `divMod` l
    mapM_ (\j -> MV.modify vec (+k) j) [0..l-1]  -- side note, this is just
                                                 -- fmap (+k) vec, but MVector is not
                                                 -- a functor. Is there a better way?
    mapM_ (\j -> MV.modify vec (+1) (j `mod` l)) [i+1..i+x]
```

where `i` is the index I'm looking to derive inside `step`. I'm doing this because the actions here need to eventually be wrapped inside an `until` and repeated until a predicate is satisfied, and freezing and thawing every cycle sounds ludicrously expensive.

Comment: Yes I see it. Shouldn't I have to `(unsafe)Thaw` again before I can write?

Comment: Unsafe freezing is in principle very cheap, in fact a no-op. And no, I don't think you'd have to thaw anything, provided you strictly evaluate the max-index before resuming the monadic computation. But better test&bench it...

Comment: @leftaroundabout hrm I'm confused then. What does `unsafeFreeze` do if not ensure that the MVector in-place freezes to an immutable `Vector`? If that's already been done, how can I then write to that position in memory?

Comment: `unsafeFreeze` does not ensure anything, that's why it's called _unsafe_. It simply pretends the memory associated with a mutable vector actually belongs to an immutable one. Of course that can go catastrophically wrong when you clobber that memory whilst something is still processing the frozen version, but for a pure scanning operation like `maxIndex` I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be ok mutating the memory again _after the index has been found and is in NF_. But I'm not completely sure about this.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, my understanding is that what you say is true for unboxed vectors: unsafe freezing and thawing do nothing. For boxed vectors, I believe freezing and thawing actually twiddle some bits that the GC cares about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see lots of talk about unsafe freezing which seems suspect since you plan to mutate this memory later, thus violating the assurance you are implicitly giving when calling `unsafeFreeze`.

My suggestion is to just write an imperative-style maxIndex function.  The below is typed but not tested:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MV
import           Control.Monad.ST
import           Control.Monad               (mapM_)

maxIndex :: (Ord a, MV.Unbox a) => MV.MVector s a -> ST s (Maybe Int)
maxIndex mv | len == 0  = pure Nothing
            | otherwise = Just <$> go 0 0
 where
 len = MV.length mv
 go n i | i >=len   = pure n
        | otherwise = do
     nVal <- MV.unsafeRead mv n
     iVal <- MV.unsafeRead mv i
     if nVal < iVal then go i (i+1)
                    else go n (i+1)
```

Comment: Question is, if you mutate a tree in the forest and the statis-demanding elves are already gone, does it still make a noise?

Comment: This worked great for me, and mucking with the exact promises made by a function named `unsafe` seemed ill-advised. Thanks for your help! For what it's worth, I realized too-late that I needed to freeze these results anyway to store in a `Data.Set.Set`, since my predicate is `Data.Set.member`. I opted to ignore mutability and just generate a bunch of immutable Vectors for this implementation, but the insights gleaned are still immensely useful!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered freezing the vector with `unsafeFreeze` which is supposed to be fast (i.e. `Θ(1)`)? For example you can define `maxIndex` for mutable vectors like this:

```
maxIndex = fmap V.maxIndex . V.unsafeFreeze
```

This assumes that you have imported the following:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed         as V
```

`unsafeFreeze` doesn't actually copy any data and should be fast, but it would be interesting to run a criterion benchmark to see if this approach is actually faster compared to an explicit loop.

Comment: I expect this should work for his situation since he needs the maxIndex prior to performing mutation, but if there was an operation like `get max index ; mutation 1 ; force max index ; mutation of max index` then I'd strongly suspect that let floating and other optimizations could get you the index as the array stands after the first mutation.  This complexity is why I discourage the unsafeFreeze option.